# Issue with elegantly accumulating errors using Either[String, B] in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to parse a csv row here and each field can be a different type. To handle the error accumulation I am using Either[String, B] where the String is an error message and B is the value. The issue here is that `B` can be different types, Option[Int], String, Array[String], resulting in my Map being type (String, Either[String,java.io.Serializable]) effectively making the Map unreusable. Is there a way (I'm definitely sure there is) to more elegantly accumulate errors while also reusing those values to populate properties on an object?

```
override def parseCsv(implicit fields: Map[String, String]): Either[String, User] = {

  val parsedValues = Map(Headers.Id -> getFieldAsString(Headers.Id),
                    Headers.FirstName -> getFieldAsString(Headers.FirstName),
                    Headers.LastName -> getFieldAsString(Headers.LastName),
                    Headers.Email -> getFieldAsString(Headers.Email),
                    Headers.TimeZone -> getFieldAsString(Headers.TimeZone),
                    Headers.Region -> getOption(Headers.Region),
                    Headers.Phone -> getOption(Headers.Phone),
                    Headers.ProfileImage -> getFieldAsString(Headers.ProfileImage),
                    Headers.Roles -> getFieldAsArray(Headers.Roles))
  val errors = parsedValues.collect { case (key, Left(errors)) => errors }
  if (!errors.isEmpty) Left(errors.mkString(", "))
  else {
    val user = new User
    user.id = getFieldAsString(Headers.Id).right.get
    user.firstName = getFieldAsString(Headers.FirstName).right.get
    user.lastName = getFieldAsString(Headers.LastName).right.get
    user.email = getFieldAsString(Headers.Email).right.get
    user.timeZone = getFieldAsString(Headers.TimeZone).right.get
    user.phoneNumber = (for {
                          region <- getOption(Headers.Region).right.get
                          phone <- getOption(Headers.Phone).right.get
                          _ = validatePhoneNumber(phone, region)
                        } yield {
                          new PhoneNumber(region, phone)
                        }).orNull
    user.profileImageUrl = getFieldAsString(Headers.ProfileImage).right.get
    user.roles = getFieldAsArray(Headers.Roles).right.get
    Right(user)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `case classes` for all types of `B`s. These case classes must extend some common trait. While populating the user object just pattern match and retrieve values.

```
sealed trait Result {
  val paramName: String
}

case class OptionInt(override val paramName: String, value: Option[Int]) extends Result

case class ArrayString(override val paramName: String, value: Array[String]) extends Result

case class StringValue(override val paramName: String, value: String) extends Result
```

now the final type would be like `Either[String, Result]`

after parsing the whole file create a `List[Result]`

If you are expecting `age` as `Option[Int]` and `firstName` as `String` then do this

```
list.foreach { result =>
    result match {
      case Option("age", value) => userId.age = value.getOrElse(defaultAge)
      case StringValue("firstName", value) => userId.firstName = value
      case StringValue("email", value) => userId.email = value
      case _ => //do nothing
    }
}
```